# Using solve_ivp to find the ground state energy of an electron

Tags: python, math, scipy, physics, ode

I'm trying to find the ground state energy of an electron using solve_ivp. The equation to solve is given by:

psi"(x)=-2 * m_e*(E - V(x)) * psi(x)

With initial conditions psi(-10a)=0, psi'(-10a)=1. V(x) is given by V_0 * (x/a)^2. Constants are defined in natural units in the code. The goal is to solve this IVP while varying E until psi(10a)=0. From pen and paper calculations, the energy returned should be 138.0214281, but when I try to plug in E=138.0214281, psi(10a) is not even close to zero. Which leads me to believe something is wrong before I can even try varying E and arriving at that answer. In fact, upon plotting the solution, I've found the graph to be way off. Here is the code I have that should be returning 0:

```py
from scipy.constants import c, m_e, eV, e
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp, solve_ivp
import numpy as np

me_ev = m_e * c**2 / e        # mass m_e in [eV]
l_bohr = 5.2918e-11           # Bohr radius [m]
convert_length = 5067730.179  # convert [m] to [1/eV] in natural units
l_ev = l_bohr * convert_length
V0 = 50
a = 10e-11 * convert_length

def V(x):
    return V0 * ((x / a) ** 2)

def eqn2(x, y, energy):
    psi, v = y
    dpsidx = v
    dvdx = -2 * me_ev * psi * (energy - V(x))
    return dpsidx, dvdx

def solve2(energy):
    y0 = [-10 * a, 1]
    sol = solve_ivp(
        eqn2,
        [-10 * a, 10 * a],
        y0,
        t_eval=np.linspace(-10 * a, 10 * a, 1000),
        args=(energy,),
        dense_output=True,
    )
    psi_L = sol.sol(10 * a)[0]
    return psi_L

solve2(138.0214281)
```

Running this gives me 1.136e+142 as psi(10a). (I've named the variable psi_L here.)

Comment: Have you verified all the constants are the same as when you do it by hand?

Comment: yes, i’ve checked that. are there any errors otherwise?

Comment: Looks like your initial conditions are wrong. Based on what you said, it should be `y0 = [0, 1]`.